# How to retrieve attachments of an ItemAttachment from Office 365 REST API?

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

Assume I have an event (that has attachments) attached to my email, then I will use the api call provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749496/how-to-retrieve-itemattachment-contents-from-office-365-rest-api) and get the event details, but I see that "Id" property is missing in the response. The same happens for messages as attachments. My problem is if I do not have the eventId or messageId, then I am not able to get their attachments.

Please see the below picture which shows the response from the provided api call [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749496/how-to-retrieve-itemattachment-contents-from-office-365-rest-api).

[image: attached picture]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve FileAttachment from ItemAttachment in Office 365 Mail REST API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239223/how-to-retrieve-fileattachment-from-itemattachment-in-office-365-mail-rest-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239223/how-to-retrieve-fileattachment-from-itemattachment-in-office-365-mail-rest-api), we can use the following api call:

GET https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/messages/[message-id]?$expand=Attachments($expand=Microsoft.OutlookServices.ItemAttachment/Item($expand=Microsoft.OutlookServices.Event/Attachments))