# Office365 Outlook REST API's for approval/rejection of messages by moderator

Tags: outlook, office365, office365api, outlook-restapi

1. In a recent post ([How to retrieve ItemAttachment contents from Office 365 REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749496/how-to-retrieve-itemattachment-contents-from-office-365-rest-api)) API mentioned to retrieve attachments from within an attached EML is in plans. Is such API already available?
2. In case of mail flow rule to send a message to a moderator. Approval mail is sent to an approver with the original mail attached as eml. Is there an API to approve/reject the message, similarly to the web buttons approve/reject?
   Thank you very much.

Comment: Any update after a year on these ?

Answer (score 0):

We were also looking for an answer to (2), but even now, apparently this is not possible via the REST API. There's one SO link that has a powershell script that claims to do this - see [Approve email message via exchange EWS API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359295/approve-email-message-via-exchange-ews-api), however, I don't see a clean solution yet.