# Approve email message via exchange EWS API

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

I have a situation where I would need to re-route messages to a different mailbox who would be the moderator. Programmatically - is there a way to approve the message I get in the moderator's mailbox? I dont see explicit support in EWS for it. Does any other API type that microsoft has support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an official approved way but the following workaround worked for me to approve and reject messages in the moderator's mailbox!

Below is a `Powershell` code that does the job!

Things to Note:

```
Item Classes: $EmailMessage.ItemClass = "IPM.Note.Microsoft.Approval.Reply.Approve" $EmailMessage.ItemClass = "IPM.Note.Microsoft.Approval.Reply.Reject"
```

`Subject - Use the Normalized subject from the approval Request email and then append Accept or Reject.`

`RecipientTo - Needs to be set to the Microsoft Exchange Approval Assistant Address.`

For Example, to Reject a mail from the `Moderator's Mailbox`:

```
$PR_REPORT_TAG = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x0031,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Binary);
$VerbResponse = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DefaultExtendedPropertySet]::Common,0x8524,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::String);  

$ReportID = $null
[Void]$Item.TryGetProperty($PR_REPORT_TAG,[ref]$ReportID)
$EmailMessage.SetExtendedProperty($VerbResponse,"Reject")
$EmailMessage.SetExtendedProperty($PR_REPORT_TAG,$ReportID)
```

Do take a look at [this](https://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2012/07/ews-managed-api-and-powershell-how-to.html) link! It's nicely explained!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible via the Graph or Outlook REST APIs.

You might be able to accomplish this using [Transport Rules](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj919238(v=exchg.150).aspx). There is a scenario documented for setting up an [Email Approval Chain](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298007(v=exchg.150).aspx#Ex3) that sounds similar. This is a configuration procedure however, not a REST API.