# Unable to retrieve 'ContentId' property of Attachment in Office365 REST Api

Tags: rest, office365-restapi

I'm trying to retrieve attachments in the Office365 rest api. Since I want to avoid downloading the entire attachments, I'm using a select clause to avoid downloading the content, which is in the ContentBytes property:

```
    $select="ContentId,ContentType,Id,IsInline,Name,Size"
```

So basically, I want to retrieve everything except the content. However, this gives the following error message (json):

```
    { 
       "error": 
          {
           "code": "RequestBroker-ParseUri",
           "message": "Could not find a property named 'ContentId' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Attachment'."
          }
    }
```

It's telling me that ContentId doesn't exist, which contradicts the [specifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#GetAttachments).

Edit: Here is the full request:

```
    GET /api/v2.0/me/messages/AAMkAGZlZjI3N2I3LTg1YWUtNDFiNC05MGI0LTVjYTVmZGI5NGI2YQBGAAAAAABzr8uDji9LRqgTCEsDv22wBwBWTXbvZW0dTKuxUGxpK4-lAAAAAAEMAABWTXbvZW0dTKuxUGxpK4-lAAC5QnKBAAA=/attachments?%24select=ContentId%2CContentType%2CId%2CIsInline%2CName%2CSize
```

Even more strange, when I do the same query without specifying any select clause, it returns me a full attachment object, including a ContentId.

Anybody can help?

Comment: `ContentId` is part of `Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment`.  Check to make sure you are specifying the correct type.  Without seeing your complete code we can not tell.

Comment: Brian, I see your point and it fits with the error message. However I don't see any REST call to look for FileAttachments instead of Attachments. Have I overlooked this?

Comment: Using the REST API you may only be able to query the common base items in the Attachment object.

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone has the same question for microsoft graph, you need to pass this filter:

```
$select=microsoft.graph.fileAttachment/contentId
```

like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/attachments?$select=microsoft.graph.fileAttachment/contentId
```

Answer (score 1):

The request that you posted is getting the message specifications but not the attachments. Since you need to get the content id, you need to add /attachments to the request with any required parameters.

GET [https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{message_id}/attachments/{attachment_id}](https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/%7Bmessage_id%7D/attachments/%7Battachment_id%7D)

So please add the attachments to your query to be able to get the content id.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. The answer was suggested by Brian's comment and I found an additional hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749496/how-to-retrieve-itemattachment-contents-from-office-365-rest-api?rq=1).
Since 'ContentId' is a  property of a FileAttachment, you need to specify that in the request, like so:

```
    $select="Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment/ContentId,ContentType,Id,IsInline,Name,Size"
```

That did the trick. Thanks for the suggestions.