# Failed to use field contentId in select or filter query for message attachments in Graph Api

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Grapg Api to fetch emails from outlook accounts.
I need to load message attachments, but without content, just fields: id, contentId.
I tried to use this request:

`GET /me/messages/{id}/attachments?$select=id,contentId`

in C#

```
await graphClient.Me
                .Messages[messageId]
                .Attachments
                .Request()
                .Select("id,contentId")
                .GetAsync();
```

Unfortunately, I got an error:

```
Message: Parsing Select and Expand failed.
 Inner error:
         AdditionalData:
         request-id: 8cec4ca6-f265-4d50-97af-3aed484ba058
         date: 12/11/2019 9:59:14 AM
 ClientRequestId: 8cec4ca6-f265-4d50-97af-3aed484ba058
 . Version:2.7.1948.0
 Microsoft.Graph.Core: Code: BadRequest
 Message: Parsing Select and Expand failed.
 Inner error:
         AdditionalData:
         request-id: 8cec4ca6-f265-4d50-97af-3aed484ba058
         date: 12/11/2019 9:59:14 AM
 ClientRequestId: 8cec4ca6-f265-4d50-97af-3aed484ba058
```

I'm guessing this is because Attachment type doesn't contain field `contentId`, however, this field contains type FileAttachments, that derives from Attachment.

Does anyone know how workaround this problem?

UPDATE:
I found solution here: [Unable to retrieve 'ContentId' property of Attachment in Office365 REST Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176483/unable-to-retrieve-contentid-property-of-attachment-in-office365-rest-api)

you need to use Select with additional type like this:

`$select=microsoft.graph.fileAttachment/contentId,id,...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from here: [Unable to retrieve 'ContentId' property of Attachment in Office365 REST Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176483/unable-to-retrieve-contentid-property-of-attachment-in-office365-rest-api)

use Select with additional type like this:

`$select=microsoft.graph.fileAttachment/contentId,id,...`