# Outlook Rest API: Download the email attachments of type .eml files using outlook rest API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I followed [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#GetAttachments) documentation to download the attachments of email.

Below is the API response.
[image: Attachments API Response]

If email attachment type is `FileAttachment`, I am able to get the file content in api response and able to save the attachment.
If email attachment type is `ItemAttachment`, I am not able to get the file content in api response. When I googled for it, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749496/how-to-retrieve-itemattachment-contents-from-office-365-rest-api) stack overflow question. I used the rest API mentioned in the answer. But it's giving `itemAttachment` content in html format. And if that `ItemAttachment` has any `fileattachment` in it, then I am unable to access it.

Is there any API available to download the `itemAttachment` as `.eml` file not as html?

Any suggestion/answers would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume by `.eml` you mean you'd like to retrieve the email in MIME format?

Retrieving an email's raw MIME content isn't supported by Microsoft Graph API at this time. This has been a common request and there is an existing [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/12253464-expose-the-entire-email-mime-stream-whole-mail-co) request for it.

If this is a hard requirement for your scenario, you may want to take a look at Exchange Web Services (EWS). The [Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa494306(v=exchg.150).aspx) object returned by EWS includes a [MimeContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa580801(v=exchg.150).aspx) property.

Comment: Marc, what is the recommended approach for getting a ScopedToken in Outlook for mobile (not OWA). At present, getCallbackTokenAsync() will not return a ScopedToken for me on Outlook for mobile. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: FYI, [MS has started](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/12253464-expose-the-entire-email-mime-stream-whole-mail-co) working on the feature. It promised to be available in beta by the end of 2018

Comment: As commented in the UserVoice, this is already (unofficially) available. Just request `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/<Message-ID>/$value`. This wil give you the .eml data.

Answer (score 1):

This is now supported on `https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/<Message-Id>/$value` endpoint