# How to save as Msg format from Microsoft Graph Message

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I collect the mailMessage from using Microsoft Graph in a Outloko Addin project. Is there a way for me to save it into a Msg format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outlook Rest API: Download the email attachments of type .eml files using outlook rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46538814/outlook-rest-api-download-the-email-attachments-of-type-eml-files-using-outloo) (.eml is the raw email as MIME)

Answer (score -1):

The .msg format is an Outlook format. You'll have to construct that yourself from spec: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx

Other people have solved this problem. For example, http://independentsoft.de has an library that does this. This is a not an endorsement and I have never seen that product in use.

Comment: independentsoft.de - wtf? Looks like scam.

Comment: independentsoft.de is not a scam. I interacted with the developer a long time ago (probably like 10+ years). He's just solving problems.