# How to download message file with an Office Outlook Web AddIn?

Tags: javascript, office365, outlook-addin, office-js

In the Office.js plugin, I am looking for a particular inbox message that should be downloaded as a message file (`.msg`, `.eml` or other). So, next time I can open that downloaded file without logging in.

How can I do this in Office.js with the Graph API?

Comment: Please refer to this SO post for graph API https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46538814/outlook-rest-api-download-the-email-attachments-of-type-eml-files-using-outloo

For make EWS request refer to this article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use [makeEwsRequestAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox#makeewsrequestasyncdata-callback-usercontext) to send request.